# When is a fence considered light weight and how do you chose if you need a heavy or a light fence?

Tags: fence

I have two other related posts regarding fences (if you are curious) . I am now trying to decide what kind of base I should implement for my fence...

Here is what I am trying to build
[image]

I would like to use one of these
[image]
but I am reading that these are used for light weight fences
The question is: is my fence built like below a heavy one? (it will span 12' and it will be made of cedar boards (1x-2 or 3 or 4-6x8')
How do you decide when you need a heavy or a light weight fence?

Comment: I don't know the tipping point, but that is not a light weight fence.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific definition of what 'lightweight' would mean for a fence. But, in general, one could probably argue that a fence that is mostly decorative is lightweight. A 3' high vinyl post and rail fence would be lightweight.

An 8' wood privacy fence would not.

You might be able to use these, but I'd want them sunk into concrete so that you have a solid enough base to with stand the horizontal loads the fence in the picture would be exposed to due to wind.

Comment: I have a friend who installed a segment of the same length with these post supports only. His fence is 6' (higher than mine) and it is the regular fence that you see everywhere.. I guess that is a heavier fence than mine

Answer (score 0):

I think "light weight" in this context doesn't refer specifically to the mass of the fence, but rather the size and overall use of the fence.  Just as an over-simplified example, a 3' fence in an enclosed non-windy area is going to be subjected to less forces than a 6' fence in a windy area.

Generally speaking, if you want your fence to last, the best thing to do is sink your posts several feet into the ground. Depending on where you live and if there is frost will impact the depth they need to be buried.  Those stakes can be useful for one-off areas when you can't dig, such as if a large tree stump is underground, but I'd be hesitant to build anything but a temporary fence anchored solely with those stakes.

Comment: I am wondering if there are any standards for fences ...